# Не работает команда random у бота на discord.py. В консоли пусто

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа, discord, discord.py

Бот просто не отвечает на команду. Если не ввести первое или второе число, то он об этом напишет, а если ввести всё правильно, то следом не последуют никакой реакции, но при этом работают абсолютно все другие команды. В консоли пустота.

### Код:

---

```
@bot.command()
async def random(ctx, num1 = None, num2 = None):
    author= ctx.message.author
    avatar = author.avatar_url
    if num1 != None:
        if num2 != None:
            x = int(msg1.content)
            y = int(msg2.content)
            if x < y:
                value = random.randint(x,y)
                embed=discord.Embed(title='Случайное число', description=f'{author.mention}, вот ваше число: \n**{value}**')
                embed.set_author(name=f"{author}", icon_url=f"{avatar}")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                await ctx.send("Первое число больше второго")
        else:
            await ctx.send('Вы не ввели наибольшее число!')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Вы не ввели наименьшее число')
```

---

[image: Как всё выглядит из чата]

Comment: В строчках `x = int(msg1.content)`  и `y = int(msg2.content)`, что такое у вас `msg1` и `msg2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых у вас не заданны переменные `msg1` и `msg2` - возможно вы имели ввиду `x = int(num1)` и `y = int(num2)`

Во-вторых название модуля `random` совпадает с названием функции - или переименуйте функцию или замените `import random` на `import random as rand`

---

Итоговый код:

```py
import random as rand


@bot.command()
async def random(ctx, num1 = None, num2 = None):
    author= ctx.message.author
    avatar = author.avatar_url
    if num1 != None:
        if num2 != None:
            x = int(num1)
            y = int(num2)
            if x < y:
                value = rand.randint(x,y)
                embed=discord.Embed(title='Случайное число', description=f'{author.mention}, вот ваше число: \n**{value}**')
                embed.set_author(name=f"{author}", icon_url=f"{avatar}")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                await ctx.send("Первое число больше второго")
        else:
            await ctx.send('Вы не ввели наибольшее число!')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Вы не ввели наименьшее число')
```

На будущее: смотрите ошибку интерпретатора питона

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало